# Analytic formula of degree of a map

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

The analytic formula for the degree of map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by

> $\mathrm{deg} f=\int D(x)\mu(f(x)) \, dx$

where $D$ denotes the jacobian and $\mu(a)$ is a smooth function such that $\int\mu(a) \, da=1$. The function $\mu(a)$ can be chosen arbitrarily as long as the integral of the degree exists.

How can I use this definition to find the degree of map from $S^2\to S^2$?

Comment: You need to use the definition for the degree of a map between manifolds, not just $\mathbb{R}^n$. In your case, $deg(f) = \int_{S^2} f^*\omega$, where $\omega \in \Lambda^2(S^2)$ is such that $\int_{S^2}\omega = 1$.

Comment: can't i use stereographic projection to map the sphere to euclidean space?

Comment: From the formula, the degree is evidently invariant under diffeomorphism, so yes you can try $S^2 \simeq \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: I cannot understand, how to choose a proper $\mu(a)$ function. How should I think on this?

Comment: By scaling, we have $\int_{S^2}f^*\omega = deg(f)\int_{S^2}\omega$ for all $\omega \in \Lambda^2(S^2)$ with $\int_{S^2}\omega \neq 0$. So you can choose any $\mu$ that doesn't integrate to $0$. There are also other ways to compute the degree, such as using a regular value.